# Distribution of a projected multivariate t variable

Tags: t-distribution, multivariate-distribution

Say $\boldsymbol x \sim t_5(\boldsymbol\mu, \boldsymbol\Sigma)$ is a $p$-dimensional multivariate t distributed random variable with $\boldsymbol \mu \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $\boldsymbol \Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$. Be $\boldsymbol w \in \mathbb{R}^p$ a constant vector.

What are the probability density and distribution of $\boldsymbol w^T \boldsymbol x \in \mathbb{R}$? Are there an analytical expressions for the pdf / cdf?

Comment: If this is a self-study question then please add that tag [tag:self-study] and tell us your thinking so far so someone can help you get unstuck.